# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros a un modal en codeigniter con Ajax?

Tags: ajax, json, codeigniter

Tengo una situación con el relleno de un modal con Codeigniter. Recibo datos de una pagina principal y estos los envío mediante ajax a un Controller, el cual consulta un Model que retorna el resultado de una consulta a la db:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', 'a', function(){

   var id= $(this).attr("value");
   var tipo=$("#tipo"+id).val();

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     //llamada al controller y su función
     url: "<?php echo base_url('Estudiantes/datosficha')?>",
     data: {"id": id, "tipo" : tipo},
     success: function(res) {

         $('#edit').modal('show');
         $('#titulo').html("<legend>"+res.titulo+"</legend>");

     }
  });
 });
});
```

recibo los datos en el controller de la siguiente manera:

```
public function datosficha()
{
   $idm=$this->input->post('id');
   $tipom=$this->input->post('tipo');

   //llamada al modelo  el cual regresa el resultado de una consulta a la bd
   $this->load->model('consultas');
   $resultm=$this->consultas->getFicha($tipom,$idm);
  echo json_encode($resultm); 
}
```

Pero al imprimir el modal, me salen valores undefined. No se si estoy enviando de una manera incorrecta los datos por ajax o si se me esta pasando algo en el código. Saludos y gracias por sus respuestas. :D

Comment: Utiliza el 'console.log(res)' antes del 'if(res)' para ver que lo que te devuelve el controlador está bien.Para ver el resultado pulsa F12 y entra en console. Al parecer primero lo tratas como un bollean y después quieres sacar un valor.

Comment: hola gracias por comentar, el problema es que ni siquiera envía los parámetros al controlador. Cuando imprimo res, me devuelve solo valores nulos.

Comment: Prueba a ver si los datos que envias mediante el ajax están bien, haz un console.log() del id y tipo a ver si recoge bien los pàrámetros.

Comment: Si de hecho ya use debugger para ver si manda los datos correctos, y el problema es que el controlador no recibe los parametros, la ruta del controlador también la probe y es correcta.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de ver los errores es utilizar el .fail() que tiene ajax para debuggear. Prueba a ver si con esto puedes encontrar el error que te puede estar dando.

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         //llamada al controller y su función
         url: "<?php echo base_url('Estudiantes/datosficha')?>",
         data: {"id": id, "tipo" : tipo},
         success: function(res) {

             $('#edit').modal('show');
             $('#titulo').html("<legend>"+res.titulo+"</legend>");

         }
      }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){ console.log(xhr); console.log(status); console.log(error); });
```

En caso de que te lo solucione o te de algún error que no sepas solucionar comenta e intentaremos otra cosa.